# How do I use Ajax to send to a RESTful API using the data property of Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

If my API is like this,

```
/controller/action/var1/something/var2/somethingelse
```

And my controller is expecting data in that fashion, how can I use the data property of Ajax to send var1 and var2?  It doesn't use the querystring, so I cannot do [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/),

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

My RewriteRule keeps me from doing this,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It will never get the `?` querystring values.

Isn't the only way to do this by building a URL outside of the .Ajax function first?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to build the URL for the AJAX post. The `data` parameter will be sent in the request body but your API is reading it off the URL.

Comment: @Jasen In other words, my RewriteRule is fighting me, right?

Comment: How does the RewriteRule allow your API to publish such a URL?

Comment: @Jasen I did it myself, which is the problem I think.  I am trying to do things RESTfully, and so I didn't want any querystring ?var=something type URL the user would see.

Comment: Then I guess you'll need a new rule for `/api` routes?